# Ordering the hyperreals and infinitesimals

Tags: nonstandard-analysis

I'm just getting into the hyperreals and infinitesimals and I would like to understand how one can determine when e is <, = or > g (where e and g are elements of the the infinitesimals). How does one order this field?

Comment: Can you only order the standard part?

Comment: Anything called the hyperreals is an ordered field. What definition of hyperrreals are you working with?

Answer (score 2):

The ordering of a$^1$ hyperreal field is part of its algebraic structure: we say $a<b$ iff $b-a$ has a square root (and this works for *all* $a,b$ in the field). So as soon as you know the algebraic structure, you know the ordering.

---

More interestingly, your question could also be asked in terms of *representations*, analogously to decimal representations of real numbers: is there an analogue of decimal representation for hyperreals such that comparing representations is "reasonably simple"?

Unfortunately, the answer to this question is **no**: in a precise sense, hyperreal fields are "less explicitly describable" than $\mathbb{R}$ itself. For example, in the usual construction of a hyperreal field $H$ via an ultrapower over $\mathbb{N}$ our hyperreals are equivalence classes of sequences of real numbers, and each sequence in a given class can be thought of as a "name" for that class. Now so far this is reminiscent of the definition of reals as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences; however, it turns out that however we build this ultrapower there will be no good way to either pick canonical representations of hyperreals or to compare two representations in general.

In fact, it's consistent with ZF (= set theory without the axiom of choice) that no hyperreal fields exist at all. This means that we can never have *too* concrete a representation system for a given hyperreal field, since otherwise we could in ZF alone reconstruct that field from that representation system.

---

$^1$Per Mark S.'s comment above, there isn't a single hyperreal field; roughly speaking, a hyperreal field is *any* field which contains $\mathbb{R}$, is sufficiently rich, and has an appropriate transfer principle.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, Noah. I got hung up on trying to work out what would be the result of subtracting one hyperreal from another: e.g. compare monad(0) - monad(0+e) with monad(0) - monad(0+f) where e, f are different elements of the infinitesimals near 0. I looks to me like the result should be "compare e with f". Can I determine which of the 2 elements are greater, or do I just accept it as an axiom? Am I even allowed to perform such an operation and remain within the realm of explicability?

Comment: Sorry - I just realized that your explanation states that there is no way to compare them. In that case, is it true that monad(x) is not ordered?

Comment: @Spanki I don't really understand what you're asking. The whole hyperreal field (whichever one you're using) is ordered. You ask "Can I determine which of the 2 elements are greater" - based on *what information*?

Comment: @Spanki monad(0) and monad(0+$e$) are the same set when $e$ is infinitesimal. So if your "-" denotes [a relative complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement), both of those differences are $\varnothing$. And if your "-" means "the set of differences", then both are monad(0). Either way, the comparison of $e$ with $f$ does not affect the calculation, so I don't think you wrote what you meant to. monad($x$) for some $x$ is ordered since an entire hyperreal field is ordered, as Noah said in the first sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Mark! I think that I need to finish Keisler's FOUNDATIONS OF INFINITESIMAL CALCULUS and digest it for a bit...